# LibGDX All Libraries got removed after IDE restart

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx, ide

I have a game written in Java with LibGDX. After closing my IDE (IntelliJ) and  shut down my PC, opened IntelliJ again and this happened:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L07RB.png)

It looks all Libraries got removed but after a quick check they are all there. I really dont know how this could happen.
I hope you can help me.

Have a great day!

Comment: Is that a Gradle project? Try to delete `.idea` directory and reimport it from `build.gradle`.

Comment: Yeah its a gradle project